# TreeMap returns null value in field that was just changed

Tags: java, android, null, treemap

I'm trying to count the frequency of words in a `TreeMap`. I'm reading a file and passing the lines to a `StringTokenizer` and converting it afterwards to a string word by word (currentword).

If `currentword = "one"` then it puts it on the map, but if the second word is `one` again instead of fetching `frequency` = 1 it gets `null` again!

```
final StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(currentLine, " \0\t\n\r\f.,;:!?'"); 

while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) { 

        String currentWord = parser.nextToken();

        Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord); 

        if (frequency == null) { 
            frequency = 0; 
        } 
        frequency++;
        frequencyMap.put(currentWord, frequency);
    }
```

Comment: why the `final` on currentWord?

Comment: Its not clear what you want here.

Comment: im counting the frequency of words with a treemap

Comment: @Hanno Binder, it's a matter of choice actually. but i think it's best practise to keep final **variables** (only variables, not class fields, nor classes or functions) on method parameters (to avoid parameters being changed by the method) or on variables used by anonymous inner classes..

Comment: I agree, it's a matter of taste :) - But: `final` for method parameters is pretty useless as a method can *never* change the values of variables passed to it to be visible outside the method itself.

Comment: that's true, but what if i don't want a method to be able to modify it's parameters? then i'd use final. i know it's not very common but i have stumbled upon it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it works fine to me:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] words = { "x", "one", "y", "one" };

        for (String word : words) {
            Integer frequency = map.get(word);
            if (frequency == null) {
                frequency = 0;
            }
            frequency++;
            map.put(word, frequency);
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{one=2, x=1, y=1}
```

See if you can come up with a similar short but complete program which demonstrates your problem - possibly by gradually cutting down your "real" code to something similar.

Comment: im getting {hello=1, hello=1} using stringtokenizer
if i display the current word i get 'hello' and 'hello'

Comment: @user1173527: I suspect you've got two different strings which both just look like "hello". Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program like mine?

Comment: you were right, that is the case. do you know how i can strip all the formatting and the invisible chars? i've used normalize and to lowercase but that doesnt seem to help

Comment: @user1173527: What do you mean by "formatting"? What "invisible chars" are you getting? Have you dumped out the exact sequence of Unicode code points in the string? Where is this string even coming from?